# Calculate column percentages using SQL in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table called 'DEMO'. It has a column called 'SEX' with records, i.e. 'Male', 'Female' or blank.

I want to find the percentage of 'Males' by:

(Counting 'Males' / (Total records - Blank records)) * 100

all in a single query.

I'm using MS Access 2010 with a .accdb file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Crosstab query to separate the values.
Create a new query with the formula, turn on totals so you only get one line in the return.
Clunky, but effective.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would do this normally except I've got a 100 queries like this to create. The idea is to 'generate' the SQL query statements in Excel, i.e. a single SQL query is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

With Access you can't use `CASE WHEǸ` syntax, though`IIF` is similar :

```
SELECT
  SUM(IIF(SEX = 'Male', 1.0, 0.0))
  / COUNT(*) AS RATIO
FROM
  DEMO
WHERE
  SEX <> ''
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and the help. Doesn't seem to be supported on MS Access though. :(

Comment: `CASE WHEN` must be replaced by `IIF` with Access

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer that psadac gave with a slight change and it seemed to work fine for me. I am using Access 2010.

```
SELECT Sum(IIf([SEX]= "Male",1,0))/Count(*) AS Ratio
FROM DEMO
HAVING (((Sum(IIf([SEX]= "Male",1,0))/Count(*)) Is Not Null));
```